# navigationController issue

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

     audiChassisInputViewController = [[myAudiChassisInputViewController alloc] init];    

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:audiChassisInputViewController animated:YES];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

    UIBarButtonItem *retourButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Retour" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)]; 
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setLeftBarButtonItem:retourButton];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitle:@"Chassis Input"];
    [retourButton release];

    [audiChassisInputViewController release];

}
```

and this workes...the new view is showed.

in the new view:

**myAudiChassisInputViewController.h**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    chassisInputTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    chassisInputTextView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [chassisInputTextView becomeFirstResponder];

    UIBarButtonItem *okButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(chassisOkPressed)];  
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setRightBarButtonItem:okButton];
    [okButton release];

}
```

I have no error, but there is no right bar button shown.Anyone, any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setRightBarButtonItem:okButton];
```

with this line:

```
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:okButton];
```

---

The thing is, by the time `viewDidLoad` is executed, the top item of the navigation bar (`self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem`) is still pointing to the navigation item of the *back view controller*.

The back view controller is the one that used to be the top view controller before the current top view controller was pushed onto the stack (`[[viewControllers objectAtIndex:[viewControllers count] - 2] navigationItem]`). The following snippet shows how the top item of the navigation bar is still pointing to the navigation item of the back view controller in `viewDidLoad` and it is for illustration purposes only:

```
// the view controllers currently on the navigation stack
NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
// The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.
UIViewController *backViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:[viewControllers count] - 2];
// get the navigation item of the back view controller
UINavigationItem *backNavigationItem = backViewController.navigationItem;
UINavigationItem *topItem = self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem;
if  (backNavigationItem == topItem) {
    NSLog(@"This gets logged to the console");
}
```

Comment: it works...but still I don't understand your explanation...could you please edit your answer for me?Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Go to your

**myAudiChassisInputViewController.m** file

place following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIBarButtonItem *retourButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Retour" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *itemOkey=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(chassisOkPressed)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=itemOkey;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=retourButton;
}
```

I have the valid output as follows that you want to have [image]

Hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have xib file of your class, then add the navigation controller and add the navigation bar and under that add the UIBarButton.